# Breakdown complex maven command into multiple steps in Gitlab

Tags: maven, gitlab, cicd

*What I am trying to achieve:*

I have a java project, in which my CI/CD pipeline, using Gitlab, is doing a bunch of maven commands.

I would like each command to be a stage, a step in Gitlab.

*What I tried:*

Here is my Gitlab-ci file:

```
  script:
    - mvn clean install site -U org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage jacoco:prepare-agent jacoco:report dependency:tree pmd:cpd pmd:pmd javadoc:javadoc checkstyle:checkstyle spotbugs:spotbugs
```

Issue, while I was expected to see something like this:

`build -> pitest -> jacoco -> ...`

I am just seeing a one step, one stage, like this:

`build`

Where everything is run inside this one step build. I can see the logs, this one and unique step build do run the pitest, the jacoco, etc...
But in the visual, it is just one step.

*Question:*

I hope to see multiple stages, one per maven command. How to achieve this please?

Comment: Just clone the command-line.

Comment: I could not find anything regarding command line clone. Do you have an example please?

Comment: The jacoco part, pmd, dependency:tree checkstyle and spotbugs should be part of the lifecycle and not being called via goals... your configuration is wrong... and don't try to separate these things...

Comment: agreed, this is the reason why I am asking the question, I know it is wrong (otherwise I wouldn't have asked duh), what would be a correct configuration, do you have an example?